# Pass a parameter from preamble to command

Tags: macros

I want to pass a parameter to a command that I use in several places in my document. I want to set the parameter in the preamble so that I don't have to use edit the command further down in my document.

My MWE: I have to alternative sample-sizes to report in note to table. I want to pick the correct by setting a parameter in preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\fixsmpl}[1]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{l}%
    {Sample runs from april to may}%
    {\ifstrequal{#1}{s}{Sample 2}{\PackageError{fixsmpl}{Undefined option to fixsmpl command}{}}}%
}

\def\X{s}

\begin{document}

% Works fine
\fixsmpl{s}

% Doesn't work 
\fixsmpl{\X}

\end{document}
```

I'm puzzled because I'm able to pass parameter in the example below:

```
%preamble
\newcommand{\inputtable}[2]{\input{../tables/table#1#2}}
\def\Z{2dp}

\begin{document}

\inputtable{1}{_\Z}
```

Comment: If you change your `\ifstrequal`s to `\ifdefstring`, `\fixsmpl{\X}` will work, but `\fixsmpl{s}` won't. The problem here is expansion. `\ifstrequal` compares its two arguments without expansion, i.e. without unpacking the definition of macros. So `\X` is not expanded to `s`. If you use `\ifdefstring`, the first argument has to be a macro (like `\X`), so it breaks down if you feed it `s`. Something like https://gist.github.com/moewew/8ef53a51c97e52ab33a57c73eecbe5d5 would work (because we expand the macro with `\edef`). `expl3`/LaTeX3 has more elegant string comparison macros.

Comment: Welcome back, Dagfinn, to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro `\ifstrequal` does no expansion to its arguments. One could define a new one that does, but it's probably better to avoid heavy nesting with the help of `expl3`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fixsmpl}{m}
 {
  \str_case_e:nVF { #1 } \c_dagfinn_fixsmpl_tl
   {
    \PackageError{fixsmpl}{Undefined ~ option ~ to ~ fixsmpl ~ command}{}
   }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_case_e:nn {nV} {T,F,TF,p}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fixsmplcases}{m}
 {
  \tl_const:Nn \c_dagfinn_fixsmpl_tl { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\fixsmplcases{
  {s}{Sample 2}
  {l}{Sample runs from April to May}
  {t}{Sample runs from June to September}
}

\newcommand{\X}{s}
\newcommand{\Y}{t}

\begin{document}

% Fine
\fixsmpl{s}

% Fine
\fixsmpl{\X}

% Fine
\fixsmpl{\Y}

% Error
\fixsmpl{z}

\end{document}
```

The reason for the indirection (I mean the use of `\fixsmplcases` outside `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` is to avoid the need of denoting spaces with `~`, which could be cumbersome.

You can define as many cases as you want.

[image]